# How should I go about creating a db schema for "news subscription" and connecting it with "users"?

Tags: database, database-design, database-development

On my website there's a new subscription form. And users can also register and subscribe to news after. When an anonymous user subscribes to the news, how should I better handle that? Should I create a) an inactive user for him b) and a record in the "news_subscritpion" table? The "news_subscritpion" table is connected with "users" by a foreign key by **user_id**.

Or should I instead keep in the "news_subscritpion" table only emails? Thus I won't need to create an inactive user for anonymously subscribed users.

None of the solutions is perfect as they both have downsides.

Comment: For me, an anonymous user is a user that you don't have any identifying information about. How would you be able to link a news subscription to a user that you can't identify?

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to keep the foreign key relation to the user table from the subscription table.

The main reason for this is that if a user comes to your site and changes their profile information and includes a new email address, then they would expect to have their subscription follow to the new address. You could always accommodate that by updating their subscriptions when they update their email but that relation (dependence on user from subscription) would only be captured in your code in that case instead of explicitly "spelled out" in the schema.

It is a bit ugly that you will have a bunch of anonymous user accounts but I like the relational consistency ("A users has zero or more subscriptions") then having email be just a property of subscription.